# How to decrypt Jenkins passwords from credentials.xml?

Tags: jenkins, encryption

I've taken over the project where a lot of Jenkins credentials has passwords or passphrase strings which I need to know in order to progress with the project, unfortunately these weren't documented anywhere.

I've checked the `credentials.xml` file where these credentials are stored, but they're in not plain text, e.g.:

```
<passphrase>{AAAAAAAAAAAANzxft/rDzyt8mhxpn3O72dxvVqZksL5vBJ4jNKvAjAA=}</passphrase>
```

<sup>Note: I've changed it slightly for privacy reasons.</sup>

How can I decrypt its original password based on the string above?

Comment: I am getting error with the proposed answer:
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{{xxx/wwww+yyyy/zzzz=}}"))
The + symbol is breaking the script. Any suggestion?

Comment: @JayBau Try with single brackets: `"{...}"`, remove extra once.

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of an SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683143/ (although technically it would only qualify as a duplicate if the linked question was asked on DevOps).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Luckily there is a `hudson.util.Secret.decrypt()` function which can be used for this, so:

1. In Jenkins, go to: `/script` page.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{XXX=}"))
   ```

   or:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString("{XXX=}").getPlainText())
   ```

   where `{XXX=}` is your encrypted password. This will print the plain password.

   To do opposite, run:

   ```
   println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString("some_text").getEncryptedValue())
   ```

<sup>Source: [gist at `tuxfight3r/jenkins-decrypt.groovy`](https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/eca9442ff76649b057ab).</sup>

---

Alternatively check the following scripts: [`tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt`](https://github.com/tweksteen/jenkins-decrypt),
 [`menski/jenkins-decrypt.py`](https://gist.github.com/menski/8f9980999ed43246b9b2).

---

For more details, check: [Credentials storage in Jenkins](http://xn--thibaud-dya.fr/jenkins_credentials.html).

Comment: +1, for secret files that use `SecretBytes` class, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a short snippet you can just run from the jenkins script console, to dump all of your credentials to plain text.

```java
com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().forEach{
  it.properties.each { prop, val ->
    if (prop == "secretBytes") {
      println(prop + "=>\n" + new String(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SecretBytes.fromString("${val}").getPlainData()) + "\n")
    } else {
      println(prop + ' = "' + val + '"')
    }
  }
  println("-----------------------")
}
```

A more complicated version that lists for non-system credential providers:

```java
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def indent = { String text, int indentationCount ->
  def replacement = "\t" * indentationCount
  text.replaceAll("(?m)^", replacement)
}

Jenkins.get().allItems().collectMany{ CredentialsProvider.lookupStores(it).toList()}.unique().forEach { store ->
  Map<Domain, List<Credentials>> domainCreds = [:]
  store.domains.each { domainCreds.put(it, store.getCredentials(it))}
  if (domainCreds.collectMany{ it.value}.empty) {
    return
  }
  def shortenedClassName = store.getClass().name.substring(store.getClass().name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
  println "Credentials for store context: ${store.contextDisplayName}, of type $shortenedClassName"
  domainCreds.forEach { domain , creds ->
    println indent("Domain: ${domain.name}", 1)
    creds.each { cred ->
      cred.properties.each { prop, val ->
        println indent("$prop = \"$val\"", 2)
      }
      println indent("-----------------------", 2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to modify this to get credentials from all domains, from all folders ?

Comment: @jmary I have added another example

Comment: Great thanks :-)

Comment: if you want an even simpler oneliner: `com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().forEach{println it.dump().replace(' ', '\n')}`

Comment: In a very old Jenkins implementation replace Jenkins.get() with Jenkins.getActiveInstance()

Comment: I keep coming back to this again and again, thanks mate!

Answer (score 10):

Based on Magnus' answer but as a simple one-liner with still readable output:

```
com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().forEach{println it.dump().replace(' ', '\n')}
```

Comment: Short and nice!

Answer (score 5):

@kenorb example with `hudson.util.Secret` is good. Also answers listing all credentials are very useful (thanks @ymajoros for one-liner).

These do not handle secret files though where `secretBytes` are used and still an encrypted string is shown. In such case the `SecretBytes` class needs to be used. Assuming the file is UTF-8, one can do:

```java
secret = "{....}"
new String(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SecretBytes.fromString(secret).getPlainData())
```

HTH

**Update:** This is the full solution from [my gits](https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/d4d695d11b0215c7acc8af5fe82a25bd):

```java
com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().forEach{
  it.properties.each { prop, val ->
    if (prop == "secretBytes") {
      println(prop + "=>\n" + new String(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SecretBytes.fromString("${val}").getPlainData()) + "\n")
    } else {
      println(prop + ' = "' + val + '"')
    }
  }
  println("-----------------------")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the record, The following snippet to be pasted into the console also does the job :

```java
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
    Jenkins.instance,
    null,
    null
)

for(c in creds) {
  if(c instanceof com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey){
    println(String.format("id=%s  desc=%s key=%s\n", c.id, c.description, c.privateKeySource.getPrivateKeys()))
  }
  if (c instanceof com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl){
    println(String.format("id=%s  desc=%s user=%s pass=%s\n", c.id, c.description, c.username, c.password))
  }
}
```